# How to Select from more columns but group by 1 column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT        studentnum
FROM            Atten
WHERE        (att = 'Yes') AND (unitCode = 'MMA1034') 
GROUP BY studentnum
HAVING        (COUNT(*) < 4)
```

How do i select more columns? eg, student_name as well?

Comment: `SELECT studentnum,MAX(student_name) AS student_name [...]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If student information is in Student table, then query may look like this:

```
SELECT student_name, student_birth_day, studentnum
FROM Student S
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT studentnum, count(*) as cnt
  FROM   Attendance
  WHERE (attStatus = 'Yes') 
  AND   (unitCode = 'MMA1034')
  GROUP BY studentnum
  HAVING (COUNT(*) < 4)
) A
ON A.studentnum = S.studentnum
```

Answer (score 0):

From [GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

> Each table or view column in any nonaggregate expression in the
>    list must be included in the GROUP BY list

So you have to include it in the group by if it is unaggregated in the select list.

So if you wish to have `student_name` in the select list, unaggregated, then you need something like

```
SELECT  studentnum,
        student_name
FROM    Attendance 
WHERE   (attStatus = 'Yes') 
AND     (unitCode = 'SIT103') 
AND     (CONVERT(VARCHAR, attDate, 101) < '10/10/2011') 
GROUP BY    studentnum,
            student_name
HAVING  (COUNT(*) < 4)
```

Answer (score -3):

if the student_name exist in the same table you need to pass it after your studentnum like

```
SELECT studentnum,student_name
```

if student_name exist in the different table you need to use the joins.

Comment: This doesn't work in ANSI sql, you must either have the selected columns in the GROUP BY, or use an aggregate function on them.