# how to write query for multiple columns in select and in group by only 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query

```
select t1.id,t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col1,t2.col2,sum(t2.col3) as total
From table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t1.col =@col
Group by t1.id
```

and it's giving me an error

> t1.col1 is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in
>   either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How to select multiple column with single column in group by clause?

Answer (score 2):

Simply you cannot select multiple columns with one column in `Group By` clause, except for if you put them in some group function, e.g. AVG, MIN , MAX etc , or you add all the columns in the `Group BY` clause itself.

```
  select t1.id,t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col1,t2.col2,sum(t2.col3) as total
   From table1 t1
   join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
   where t1.col =@col
   Group by t1.id , ,t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col1,t2.col2
```

Comment: i need to take only single column in group by. result should be grouped only by the col1

Comment: @Himanshu, if the other columns in the select list do not have a changing value, adding them in `Group By` shall not effect the result.

Comment: if col1=id and col2=name
and if i put like

{group by id,name}

after grouping  of id, would it again make a group for name ? i think yes it will make the all the possible groups according to the columns in the  group by clause right ?

Comment: @Himanshu, though its impossible to say something without looking at the data, but IMHO you can use aggregate functions accordingly on the column e.g if you use `MIN(name)` and omit `name` column from `Group by` clause, it shall not effect.

Comment: Solution :

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564285/how-to-select-from-more-columns-but-group-by-1-column][1]

Answer (score 0):

If t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col1,t2.col2 are numeric columns, you can have `min, max` used.
for string columns, you need to use them in your `groupby` Statement